# How does the C# compiler guarantee conversion success?

Tags: c#

I am learning with C# 7.0 in a Nutshell 7th edition. There is a portion of the text that I could not understand (page 24 & 25)

> "Implicit conversions are allowed when both of the following are true:
>
> 1) The compiler can guarantee they will always succeed.
>
> 2) No information is lost in conversion. 
>   (A minor caveat is that very large long values lose some precision when converted to double)
>
> Conversely, explicit conversions are required when one of the following is true:
>
> 1)The compiler cannot guarantee they will always succeed.
>
> 2)Information may be lost during conversion."
>
> If the compiler can determine that a >conversion will always fail, both kinds of conversion are prohibited"

Can you give me examples for when the compiler cannot guarantee conversion ?

Comment: `double` to `int`?

Comment: see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284359/when-should-i-use-cs-implicit-type-conversion-operator

Comment: the best way to learn this is to create a console app and play around, lots of fun there

Comment: Casting an IFoo interface reference to a Foo object, for example.  The compiler can't be sure that it might actually be a Bar class object that also implements IFoo.  If it is then you get an InvalidCastException at runtime.  In general any conversion that is an upcast, going from the less specialized type to a more specialized type.  Generally a bad idea but sometimes inevitable.  The floating point examples are not great, they actually succeed at runtime and you'll get a number that might surprise you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of when the compiler can't guarantee conversion would be if you are making assumptions about types at run time. A very loose example might be this

```
public int Add(object a, object b)
{
    return ((int)a) + ((int)b);
}
```

Here you are working on the assumption that you will be passed an int at runtime, for whatever reason you've lost the type safety and you are working with an object. The compiler does not and cannot know this at compile time, hence why you need the explicit cast.

This is an extreme example but hopefully it clears it up a bit for you

Answer (score 3):

The answers so far focus on value types.

For reference types there are base-class, derived class and interface conversions.

```
class A  { }       // base class
class B : A { }    // B is-an A 
class C : A { }    // C is-an A 

B b = new B(); // instance of B 
A a = b;       // ok, conversion to base class can't fail because B is an A
C c = (C) a;   // but conversion to derived could fail, a could be a B
```

Answer (score 1):

Implicit conversions exist for data type upcasts, like `short` to `int`, or `int` to `long`. Another example is `int` to `float` or `double`. Such data types can always cast to their larger counterpart data types.

The other way around is not true: a `double` can't (always) be converted to an `int`. A `long` doesn't always fit in a `int` or `short`.

Comment: to add some context an example of a explicit conversion will be string to integer, due that you can never know if the string content is a number, an alphanumeric or just a text value

Comment: `double` to `int` also has an explicit operator. @MrVoid

Comment: yeah, you are 100% correct, I just thought that just numeric values could be a bit confusing sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So is it only the data size that make the compiler determine to guarantee a conversion or not?

Comment: No. As said by MrVoid, it depends on both data types. Anything with `string` is a bad choice for example. @Coder

Comment: Sorry just read his comment. Yes that is an interesting example. Where can I to read more about this? I am trying to think like the compiler to account for possible cases.

Comment: "Anything with string is a bad choice for example.", can you elaborate @PatrickHofman? thanks

Comment: @Coder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table.

Comment: @MrVoid Well, it would be hard implicitly converting any data type from and to string.

Comment: yeah seen that way its not a very good example for the over all picture.

Comment: `double` to `int` and `long` to `int` or `short` aren't examples of case 1, but case 2. They can lose information, but they never fail. An example of a conversion that can fail would be downcasting an object of a class to a subclass.

Comment: @sepp2k My first paragraph is the other way around, and there you can convert without loss.

Comment: Because that is how Stack Overflow works @Coder. Just pick the one that helped you most.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sure, I was talking about the second paragraph. The book lists two reasons why a conversion may not be implicit: 1) it may fail or 2) it may lose information. OP asked for examples where a conversion may fail (i.e. case 1). I'm saying that you gave examples of case 2 in your second paragraph, but you didn't give any examples of case 1.

Comment: Or to put another way: a `double` *can* always be converted to `int` (there is no situation where `(int)myDouble` would ever raise an exception - unlike say `(MySubclass)myObject`), it just can't always be converted without losing information.